# What is wrong with my codes for passing Form Data and Listbox data to controller by ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anybody help me to find what is wrong with my codes for passing form data and Listbox data to controller by ajax?

Here is the ajax code:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function () {


             var button1 = "getdata";
             var listItms = $('#ChooseRight').val();   // this is Lisbox field in Razor view
             var formData = $('#GenForm').serialize();  //the Form ID of razor view
             var wildcardprodtype = $('#WildCardProdType').val();

             $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',

                url: '/Report/LongRunningProcess',  //controller name

                 data: JSON.stringify({
                     button: button1,
                     viewModel: formData,
                     ChooseRight: listItms,
                     WildCardProdType: wildcardprodtype

                }),

                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",

                async: true,

                success: function (data) {

                }

            });
```

Here is the controller, in debug, I can see the data of "button", WildCardProdType are passed properly, but not the data of viewModel and ChooseRight list. Any reason why?

```
public ActionResult LongRunningProcess(string button, ReportViewModel viewModel, List<string> ChooseRight, string WildCardProdType)

{

   ....
```

here is the @HtmlBegin form header:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "GenForm" } ))

{
```

By the way, the current razor view use ReportViewModel as this:

```
@model MVCPROD.Models.ViewModels.ReportViewModel
```

Comment: What is the structure of `ReportViewModel`?  What exact data is in `formData` and `listItems` what it gets passed to the server?

Comment: You cannot mix javacript objects and serialize form data like that. If you use `serialize()` it generated a 'query string' (e.g. `someProperty=someValue&anotherProperty=anotherValue&....`) so you need to append the other values to it

Comment: But if you have generated your view correctly, then `serialize()` will serialize all the form controls including the values from the listbox etc, so there would be no need to append anything - all you need is `data: formData,` (and remove the `contentType` option)

Comment: And since you have a view model then why in the world have you not included properties for `ChooseRight`, `WildCardProdType` etc in it

Comment: @Stephen, The thing is that I have some extra fields on the form which are not in the viewModel, so I have to pass them to together with formData, Now, it seems these extra fields data can not serialize with formData, then I have to find a way to pass them to controller. any idea? I heard somebody mentioned to use serializeObject , but I have never used it.

Comment: Read the 2nd comment :) But its a view model - you can add what ever properties to it that you want - that is the whole point of a view model! And in any case all you need is `data: formData,` and remove the `contentType` option as per the 3rd comment.

Comment: And `serializeArray()` cannot be used if your form contains checkboxes generated using `CheckBoxFor()` so its not really suitable in mvc views

Comment: @Stephen, thanks again for your quick response. Just want to clarify that it seems the serialize() or serializeArray() can only serialize the model data, any extra field data which is not included in the model will not be serialized, right? if this is the case, then I can not use serializeArray(), as I do have some extra fields need to be passed to controller. For the current form with the model data fields, there are some listbox(combox) there, if they can not passed, then I still can not pass then as model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I got another answer from another post, here it is: https://forums.asp.net/t/2136058.aspx?How+to+pass+Form+data+and+ListBox+data+to+controller+through+Ajax+, I will try it next Monday, please let me know what is your opinion about this solution, thanks

Comment: Which one? The first one is what I have already told you to do. And the 2nd is not suitable for mvc as I have already stated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164900/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user2949042).

Comment: please check this solution, this is what I meant:https://forums.asp.net/t/2136058.aspx?How+to+pass+Form+data+and+ListBox+data+to+controller+through+Ajax+

Comment: Again - WHICH ONE? there are 2 answers in that forum! And read my all my comments again carefully, including the one in chat.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sorry for the confusing. Here let me know clarify: I understand your first post - if all items of Model included in the form as form fields, no extra field, then the serialize() will serialize all form elements as data stream and pass to back controller. But for my case, there are a few extra fields: one text field and one Listbox field which are added later and they are not included in the original entity, hence they are not included in the model data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `serializeArray()` instead `serialize()` so that you can include more items in the form serialized array.

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function () {                    
                var button1 = "getdata";
                var listItms = $('#ChooseRight').val();  
                var wildcardprodtype = $('#WildCardProdType').val();
                var formData = $('#GenForm').serializeArray();                     
                //Below three lines are not required if ChooseRight, WildCardProdType elements are inside the form
                formData.push({ name: 'button', value: button1 });
                formData.push({ name: 'listItms', value: listItms });
                formData.push({ name: 'wildcardprodtype', wildcardprodtype });

                $.post(
                    '/Account/LongRunningProcess',
                    formData,
                    function (response) {

                    }
                );
            });
```

Comment: if you insist you have tried your solution, then I will retry it again next Monday and let you know the result then. Thanks you so much for your help again. Have a great weekend.